# Add only a key to a json object

Tags: python, json

I saw many questions in Stackoverflow but I didn't find what exactly responds to my query. So here goes. I use python to obtain a json object in the below format.The input is a csv file and the json object refers to the the key value pair of column name : some stat calculated. This is the core of what I have done so far

```
   df = self.readCSV() 
   counter = (df.isnull().sum())
   counter.to_json(os.path.join('/path/','data.file'))
```

> {"Column1":1,"Column2":3}

I need to append ONLY a key to it and get the following result.

> {"keyname":{"Column1":1,"Column2":3}}

Any and all help shall be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d1 = {"Column1":1,"Column2":3}
>>> d2 = {'keyname': d1}
>>> d2
{'keyname': {'Column1': 1, 'Column2': 3}}
```